# Updating video src dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, webcam

I'm making a web cam recorder using [this code](https://gist.github.com/rissem/d51b1997457a7f6dc4cf05064f5fe984).

It works fine but I want to add another functionality, like: after recording if user doesn't like the video they should be able to record another one and see that video.

So I added this piece of code inside the JavaScript file.

```
function myFunction(videoname) {
  var wait;

  if (counter == 0) {
    var x = document.createElement("VIDEO");

    if (x.canPlayType("video/webm")) {
      x.setAttribute("src", videoname);
      x.setAttribute("id", "replay")
    }
    x.setAttribute("width", "320");
    x.setAttribute("height", "240");
    x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    counter++;
  } else {
    $("#replay").remove();
    var x = document.createElement("video");

    if (x.canPlayType("video/webm")) {
      x.setAttribute("id", "replay");
      x.setAttribute("src", videoname);

    }
    x.setAttribute("width", "320");
    x.setAttribute("height", "240");
    x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");

    document.body.appendChild(x);
    wait = document.getElementById("replay");
    wait.load();
  }
}
```

`videoname` is the updated `videoname` in this case, so it works when I inspect the code it changes the video `src` in the HTML.

What I try to achieve is, when user records the video, there is a video element appears and user can see the video which they recorded. For the second video, when I click the play button, it shows the first video and then shows the second video. I mean it works somehow but it always plays the previously recorded video first and then new one. After few playbacks, it plays new video.

Any idea how can I make this work? Or does anyone faced this problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Well solution came from another part of the code.

in the same js file, videoCapture.js

```
const chunks = []
let onDataAvailable = (e) => {
  chunks.push(e.data)
}
```

this piece has to be modified. since all data stored in array, I had to clear the array when another recording function is called. so i simply declared chunks at top of the page.

```
let  chunks = []
```

and then  put chunks = [], inside the function. now it works as I expected.

```
function myFunction(videoname) {
  var wait;


    chunks = [];
```